# What does this option do?

Tags: command-line, apt, updates, sudo

I have a software installed on my computer and it hasn't been running for quite some time. I saw a potential solution to be a simple update. I'm new to the command line and would like to know what this option for `sudo` will do:

`sudo apt-get update -y`

`sudo apt-get install -y yourprogramhere`

I checked `man sudo`,`man apt`,`man get`,`man install`, and `man update`.

I looked for `-y` documentation, and couldn't find it.

Comment: The weirdest thing just happened... the program started up. I'm still interested in an answer to the question, though.

Comment: `-y` will answer yes so you will not be prompted and asked to confirm installation of updates or packages

Comment: So why didn't you look in `man apt-get`?

Comment: Not there in my studies yet! Thanks!

Comment: Seems... dangerous.

Comment: "would like to know what this option for `sudo` will do […] I looked for `-y` documentation, and couldn't find it." – Hint #1: What command does this option appear after? Hint #2: It's not `sudo`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is in [man **apt-get**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man8/apt-get.8.html)

> **-y, --yes, --assume-yes**
>
> Automatic yes to prompts; assume "yes" as answer to all prompts and
>   run non-interactively. If an undesirable situation, such as changing a
>   held package, trying to install an unauthenticated package or removing
>   an essential package occurs then apt-get will abort. Configuration
>   Item: APT::Get::Assume-Yes.

It is however not mentioned in [man **apt**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/apt.8.html) for this reason:

> **apt** provides a high-level commandline interface for the package
>   management system. It is intended as an end user interface and enables
>   some options better suited for interactive usage by default compared
>   to more specialized APT tools like **apt-get**(8) and apt-cache(8).
>
> Much like apt itself, **its manpage is intended as an end user
>   interface and as such only mentions the most used commands and options
>   partly to not duplicate information in multiple places and partly to
>   avoid overwhelming readers with a cornucopia of options and details.**