# Issue with upgrading package. | sudo apt list --upgradable empty, but shows 3 not upgraded

Tags: apt, package-management

I have a Ubuntu 20.04 VPS. On this server when I run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`, it shows there are 3 upgradable packages, but when I run the upgrade command or force upgrade nothing upgrade or install. When I check `sudo apt list --upgradable` it shows nothing.

What could be the reason for this? And how do I fix this issue?

```
root@server:~# du -sh /var/cache/apt/archives
40K     /var/cache/apt/archives
root@server:~# sudo apt-get clean
root@server:~# sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/redis-server/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:3 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/virtubox:/nginx-ee/xUbuntu_20.04  InRelease [1,537 B]
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wordops/nginx-wo/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:10 http://mariadb.mirrors.ovh.net/MariaDB/repo/10.5/ubuntu focal InRelease [7,767 B]
Fetched 9,304 B in 1s (10.8 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
root@server:~# sudo apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
root@server:~#
```

Comment: It is not necessary to use `sudo` at a root prompt.

Comment: You mean if I login as root user no need to use ```sudo```?

Comment: Do you have any [held packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/640986/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-packages-held-back-from-upgrade)? Do you get a different result if you use `apt dist-upgrade` instead of `apt upgrade`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [man apt-get](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/apt-get.8.html):

> **-u, --show-upgraded**    Show upgraded packages; print out a list of all packages that are to be upgraded.    Configuration Item:
> **APT::Get::Show-Upgraded**.

so try running either:

```
sudo apt upgrade -u
```

or the same `-u` option can be specified in the following two froms:

```
sudo apt upgrade --show-upgraded
```

or:

```
sudo apt upgrade -o APT::Get::Show-Upgraded=true
```

alike should give you more information than `sudo apt upgrade` alone or `sudo apt list --upgradable` among which should be the names of those `3 not upgraded.` packages so you can know more with:

```
dpkg -l package-name
```

and see APT’s detailed response  output with:

```
sudo apt install package-name
```

Those three packages are most likely either packages with unsatisfied dependencies or packages with unspecified version numbers.

It could be also that their installation would require the removal of some installed packages and in which case, you can tell `apt` to curry on and upgrade those packages which will result in the removal of some other conflicting packages like so:

```
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

From [man apt](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/apt.8.html):

> **full-upgrade** (apt-get(8))    full-upgrade performs the function of
> upgrade but will remove currently installed    packages if this is
> needed to upgrade the system as a whole.

If you are wondering why I alternate referencing `man apt-get` and `man apt` and aren't they the same? then, please see [my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1215395) for an explanation.